# Textfield inside Form clears data on Scroll - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am facing a strange issue in swift UI.Following is the code I am using to show a Form page

```
{
    VStack {
        Form {
 
            
            Section {
                TextField("Registration ID", text: $obj.regId)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                
       
                
                TextField("Company Name", text: $obj.companyName)
                    .autocapitalization(.words)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .textContentType(.organizationName)
            }
            
            Section {
                TextField("First Name", text: $obj.firstName)
                    .autocapitalization(.words)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .textContentType(.givenName)
                
                TextField("Last Name", text: $obj.lastName)
                    .autocapitalization(.words)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .textContentType(.familyName)
            }
            
            Section {
                TextField("Email", text: $obj.email)
                    .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                    .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                
            }
            
            Button(action: save, label: {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    ………..
                }
            })
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Register with FleetDocs")
}
```

But the issue is that if I enter a value on the first text field and if I scroll the screen up , that means if the entered textfield scrolls outside the visible area of the screen , then scrolling back to the normal position is clearing the entered data in text field.
Means if I enter a value on the first field then trying to enter the last field by scrolling the screen up , after that if I scrolls down to enter the second textfield then the value already entered on the first field becomes cleared.But the state value in that text field is showing correctly.
Looking for suggestions

Comment: Not reproducible with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1. Do you use any beta? What is your `obj`?

Comment: obj is a NSManagedObject

Comment: I suspect `obj` doesn't keep the updated values as all, hence you think it's resetting. Can we see your `obj` object?

Comment: Yes It seems obj is keeping values , becuase I tried to print the "obj" object inside the button action and I can see the values entered on the text field, but it's not showing on the same text field